# only one workspace

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, workspaces

In the process of upgrading in Linux Mint, I've gotten a strange star-studded window with a spiraling spaceship but NO workspace options.

```
$ uname -a
3.1.0-1-686-pae #1 SMP Sun Dec 11 20:40:16 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

and `/etc/lsb-base` yields the distribution as: `debian "Linux Mint Xfce Edition"`.
In Linux desktops, I have formerly been able to request a workspace manager via a right click in the lower or upper border.  Now I get no response to a right click in any location!

Comment: I don't know the default key bindings of the window manager you use, but you can try <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<Left> and <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<Right> to switch betweek workspaces.

Comment: @Marco XFCE/GNOME use the same key bindings for to change between workspaces :)

Answer (score 2):

that desktop wallpaper is the default debian 6.0 ("squeeze") wallpaper, the spiral is the debian logo a and the spaceship is possibly a reference to squeeze(tm pixar)

this works in debian:
  right-click the panel (menu bar)
  left click "add to panel"
  from the list select "workplace switcher"

as far as i can tell the switcher is built into xfce-panel.

If you're missing the panel itself, you may want to  rename or delete any .xsession or .xinitrc files you have in your home directory.

Comment: many thanks, Jasen.  Actually, I had to right click on the firefox logo in the lower right of the desktop.  That gave me an option:  preferences.  Then I had the option to put in place as many workspaces as possible.

Comment: The spaceship is not only a reference to Squeeze, but a part of the "Debian - Universal OS" campaign :)